# How I can iterate over borrowed array?

Tags: reference, iterator, rust

I thought that it should be something like this, but I cannot iterate over an borrowed array.

```rust
fn print_me<'a, I>(iter: &'a I) where I: Iterator<Item = i32> {
    for i in *iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];
    //let numbers = &numbers;
    print_me(numbers.iter());
}
```

But Rust complains:

```
<anon>:15:12: 15:26 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&_`,
    found `core::slice::Iter<'_, _>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `core::slice::Iter`) [E0308]
<anon>:15   print_me(numbers.iter());
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4):

An iterator is a regular object; you work with an iterator directly, not typically through references—and certainly not typically through immutable references, for taking the next value of an iterator takes `&mut self`. And a reference to an iterator is quite different from an iterator over references.

Fixing this part, you then have this:

```rust
fn print_me<I: Iterator<Item = i32>>(iter: I) {
    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

This doesn’t fix everything, however, because `[T].iter()` produces a type implementing `Iterator<Item = &T>`—it iterates over *references* to each item. The most common fix for that is cloning each value with the handy `.cloned()` method, which is equivalent to `.map(|x| x.clone())`.

Here, then, is the rest of what you end up with:

```rust
fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];
    print_me(numbers.iter().cloned());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does make sense. The other possibility is change a function as it use a reference.

Comment: @lofcek: it is not useful to take an iterator by mutable reference; if `I` implements `Iterator`, `&mut I` does too, so you can pass a mutable reference to an iterator in that way. There’s even the `by_ref(&mut self) -> &mut Self` method on `Iterator` for convenience of chaining.